# is not having vs isn't having- meaninig difference

Tags: grammar, no-not

I heard a sentence in latest South Park episode and suddenly I have questioned a sentence.

> The hardest part is not having any followers, i used to go to places just to show them where i was

What happens if we alter this sentence to:

> The hardest part isn't having any followers, i used to go to places just to show them where i was

I think the meaning completely changes, why is that, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the meaning changes.  It's easier to see why this is so if you move the gerund to the subject position.  I'll do this with an example sentence similar to the one you heard in South Park:

> Sentence 1: The hardest part is **not seeing her everyday** 
> Sentence 2: The hardest part isn't **seeing her everyday**
>
> Sentence 1A: **Not seeing her everyday** is the hardest part. 
> Sentence 2A: **Seeing her everyday** isn't the hardest part.

When I hear sentences 1 and 1A, I believe the speaker is telling me what the hardest part is.  When I hear sentences 2 and 2A, I believe the speaker is eliminating something from the list of things the hardest part might be. This also leads me to assume that the speaker will go on and tell me what the hardest part actually is: "The hardest part isn't seeing her everyday; the hardest part is listening to her bitch about her boyfriend all the time."

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly the difference in the way the two versions are parsed, but either version can have the same to meanings. One way to parse the expression is to use not as a modifier of "is", the other way to parse the expression is fo not to apply to "having any followers".

Using the contraction is probably more likely to be parsed in the first sense, that is to write that "not modifies "is", while spelling out "is not" is more likely to be parsed as "not having any followers.

Comment: so their meanings are indeed different? I think not used as an adjective in first one modifying participle

Comment: Like a lot of other usages in English, context is determinant.  Standing alone, it's hard to say which is which, though the contraction lends itself to being parsed one way, and written tout lends itself to being parsed the other.